# Connection stays alive but endpoint is dead?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tcp, ubuntu-11.04

Does anyone have an idea what would cause a TCP connection (client side) to stay in the ESTABLISHED state for about 24 hours, even though the server was restarted? 
The client process stays on the recv syscall and stays that way without causing an error!

Client is on an Ubuntu 11.04 installation. This happened to me a few times already, but I can't seem to understand why or how to solve it.

Comment: What protocol is this? (The one layered directly over TCP. The one that specifies what the bytes sent mean, who sends them, when, and so on.)

Answer (score 3):

The connection is remaining ESTABLISHED on one side and non-existent on the other because that's the state it was in after the server restarted. The client has no idea the server restarted and the server has no idea the client thinks it's still connected. Unless the client attempts to use the connection, it will remain this way forever. (Unless keepalives are enabled, in which case it will remain this way for typically around two days.)

Why is the client waiting forever for the server?! Either the client or the protocol is broken. If the client isn't following the protocol, the client is broken. If the protocol doesn't specify how to detect a dead connection, the protocol is broken.

TCP does not detect a dead connection for an end that is not trying to send data. So every protocol layered on top of TCP *must* be designed to take this into account. If this stuck connection is not acceptable behavior, then this protocol is broken because it allows this unacceptable behavior (or the client is broken for not following the protocol).

Does the protocol specification really say to wait *forever* for data? If so, I'd question the sanity of the protocol's developers.